# How to show flickr 1,060,834 Images in Windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, flickr

Basically i am developing an app in **Windows phone 7 mango , C# ,** who will display 1,060,834 images from flickr nature photostream,

i used flicker api

http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&extras=url_o&photoset_id=**[not able to find photoset id]**+ "&nojsoncallback=1&format=json&api_key=[mykey]&sort=date-posted-desc&extras=url_m&per_page=100000000000000";

and parse the json data,

but problem is this services returns only 500 images , i want to load another 500 images when i'm reach at 500th picture ,

the photostream i'm using is : http://www.flickr.com/groups/naturegroup

also i am not able to find photoset id

so my questions are :

```
- How could i get all images from flickr photostream 
- How could i know photostream photoset id ?
```

([here is](http://www.flickr.com/groups/naturegroup) photostream that i'm referring)

Comment: Have you checked if there's some sort of paging mechanism? Like &page=1

Comment: No WebService author would allow result sets of 100000000000000. That would be enough to bring down the most powerful of servers with very few requests.

Comment: On top of that, no phone user would want you to download 1 million images on their phone in one hit - paging is the way forwards. On top of that, the FlickrAPI limits you to a [maximum of 500 images per request](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.galleries.getPhotos.html).

Answer (score 3):

Use the [FlickrNet API Library](http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/). It also supports Windows Phone 7.

There is an example of using this library to [retrieve subsequent pages](http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ExampleGettingMoreThanOnePage&referringTitle=Examples) on the project's pages, as well as a number of other [examples](http://flickrnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home).

There is also an article on CodeProject: [A Simple ASP.NET Flickr Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/127155/A-Simple-ASP-NET-Flickr-Application).